# How to save the multiple output images in a folder using PIL, Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The show_result function in this code can save a single output image using the following function. But, I would like to save all output images in a folder. But it doesn't work. Please help to save all output images in a folder using python.

```
def show_result(image_path, bboxes, probs, ratio):
   image = Image.open(image_path)
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
   font = ImageFont.truetype(font='./font/FiraMono-Medium.otf',
                      size=np.floor(3e-2 * image.size[1] + 0.5).astype('int32'))
   thickness = (image.size[0] + image.size[1]) // 512
   for key in bboxes:
     bbox = np.array(bboxes[key])

     new_boxes, new_probs = non_max_suppression_fast(bbox, np.array(probs[key]), overlap_thresh=0.2)
     for jk in range(new_boxes.shape[0]):
         (x1, y1, x2, y2) = new_boxes[jk, :]
         (left, top, right, bottom) = get_real_coordinates(ratio, x1, y1, x2, y2)
         label = '{} {:.2f}'.format(key, new_probs[jk])

         # draw frame
         draw.rectangle(
             [left, top, right, bottom],
             outline='white', width=thickness)

         # draw text
         label_size = draw.textsize(label, font)
         text_origin = np.array([left, top - label_size[1]])
         draw.rectangle(
             [tuple(text_origin), tuple(text_origin + label_size)],
             fill='white')
         draw.text(text_origin, label, fill='black', font=font)
  del draw
  image.show()
  #image.save('./results/small/pokemon_.bmp', 'BMP') 
  #save for multiple images 
  for index, new in enumerate(image):
      new.save(f"./Results/small/{index}.bmp")         


def load_data_name(dataset_dir):
   names = []
   for file in os.listdir(dataset_dir):
      names.append(file)
   return names


if __name__ == '__main__':
   data_path='./data/small/'
   data_name=load_data_name(data_path)
   for i in range(len(data_name)):
       test(net='vgg', weights='weights/vgg_frcnn.hdf5', image_path=data_path+data_name[i])
```

Comment: What's the actual issue please? You can save one image in a folder so why can't you save two? Or more? Is your disk full?

Comment: new.save(f"./Results/small/FOLDER/{index}.bmp") ?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I can't understand the reason.